# Wubi for Windows 7 on Sony Vaio is not Working

Tags: installation, wubi, windows-7

I have installed Ubuntu using Wubi on my Windows 7 machine (Sony Vaio). Everything installed perfectly, but whenever I reboot my system there is no Ubuntu (there is no dual boot menu). I checked my Windows setting and it seems there is only Windows (it could not recognize Ubuntu).

Could anyone help me how to solve this problem.

Answer (score -3):

Please remove Wubi completly from Control-Panel (Add/remove softwares).
Wubi sometimes can cause some problems, and installing with a Disk or a DOK (Disk On Key) is better. (And you have to remove Wubi for installing normally)

Download the ISO file and make a disk or a DOK.
there are guides in the Ubuntu sites for creating both.

If you need to ask something, ask (: